# How to profile and approach a slow PHP application

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, apache

I have an Enterprise PHP application hosted on RHEL 5.5. It works with MySQL and perl scripts.

It is causing regular CPU and memory spikes. I can see httpd and MySQL processes in **top** command output.

I know I can profile individual php scripts. But is there a way which can give me statistics about how many web hits my application got, which script got called with that arguments and what was its execution time?

I intend to start refactoring and optimizing the top 10 scripts that shows up in the result, till the results become acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Your first port of call is your web server logs. You should be able to correlate the spikes in CPU usage with urls.

Consider using a log analyser such as [webaliser](http://www.webalizer.org/) which can extract lots of useful usage data from the apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

For webserver statistics you can always use awstats it is a great handy tool for statistical information about no of hits,dynamic reports etc. http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker